# Position an element in the middle of 2 text elements

Tags: css

Here's a code snippet: http://dabblet.com/gist/8673746

I want to position `.sign` at the middle between the right edge `.op1` and the left edge of `.op2` without using JavaScript.

Also, the plus signs need to be aligned.

An option is to set `text-align:left` on `.op1`, but I'd rather have it be right aligned.

Is it possible using CSS only?

Comment: Not possible.. with css. I even doubt whether it is possible using javascript.

Comment: is this you are trying to do ? http://dabblet.com/gist/8674064

Comment: You better add `0` to the less digit numbers and try..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using `position:absolute` too:

```
.sign
{
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  padding:10px;
}
```

Check this http://dabblet.com/gist/8674039

Another thing you can use to complete this is set just padding `top-bottom` like this

http://dabblet.com/gist/8674139

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
.container > * {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I think OP wanted to leave `.op1` and `.op2` right aligned so removing the `text-align:center;` comes close.

Comment: or as you said, add text-align left for .op1 and center align for .sign

Comment: then add text align center just for .sign

Comment: .sign
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
}